# Run command in background with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I want to run a background script with Fabric using Bash's '&' operator.  Is there a reason the following doesn't work?  I executed this command on the server itself and it runs fine.

```
@task
def run_script():
    sudo('sh /home/ubuntu/wlmngcntl.sh start &', user='myuser')
```

I don't want to use something heavy like Celery to do this simple thing. I don't need to capture the output at all, all I want is for the task to execute this and return after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a Fabric thing, but a Linux thing.  When you close a session, the processes connected to that session are terminated.

This question has a lot of info... https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session

You could use the following (from that answer)

`sudo('nohup sh /home/ubuntu/wlmngcntl.sh start &', user='myuser')`